# How to create an api response object type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am doing an api call and getting a response back.

Suppose, the response is something like this

```
{
 data: {
 name: 'Varun', 
 id: 'szjsns3d', 
 email: 'varun.bindal@gmail.com'
 }
}
```

and this is my swift code

```
guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let createMeetingData = data else {
                return
}

do{
                let createMeetingResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: createMeetingData, options: []) as? [String : AnyObject]
```

I thought by doing `[String : AnyObject]`, I will be able to do something like this

```
print(createMeetingResponse.data.id);
```

but this throws an error

> Value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' has no member 'data'

Then I thought about creating a type for it (coming from a typescript background) but I wasn't able to find a way for doing it.

The answers which I was able to get involved using codeable for api request. (Encoding and decoding using codeable).

Can someone please help me in figuring out how I can achieve this without using codeable?

### Update

I tried using decodable but it keeps giving me error

> > Type 'CreateMeetingResponse' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable

This is how I made decodable

```
struct  MeetingResponse {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let email: String

}

struct CreateMeetingResponse:Decodable {
    let data:MeetingResponse
}
```

Comment: Why not use `Codable` in Swift4+? Else, it's if let data = createMeetingResponse["data"] as? [String: Any], let id = data["id"] as? String { print("id: \(id)")}.

Comment: Each properties of `CreateMeetingResponse` needs to be decodable. So `MeetingResponse` needs to be `Decodable` too. Then, it's missing the level `"data"`, but once done it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
if let res = createMeetingResponse["data"] as? [String:Any] {
     if let id = res["id"] as? String {
         print(id)
     }
}
```

But it's better using `Codable`

```
do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: createMeetingData)
    print(res.data.id)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}


struct DataClass: Codable {
    let name, id, email: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Marked this question as answered. 

Also mentioned why I didn't (or wasn't able) created decodable. Can you please answer what I might've missed it?

Comment: you only can do it by one of the above 2 ways